# Which method is most suitable to change the pixeltype of the raster in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I have saved a raster in the PostGIS database and want to select it as PNG. However, [ST_AsPNG](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsPNG.html) only accepts rasters with pixel type 8 BUI or 16 BUI. But in this case it is a raster with pixel type 32 BF.
The only possibility I have seen so far is [ST_Reclass](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Reclass.html). But you need to define a ['reclassarg'](https://postgis.net/docs/reclassarg.html) which makes it unnecessarily complicating for my usage, because I only want to change the pixel type.
Does anyone know a more suitable method for this purpose?

Comment: Changing a 4-byte float to an integer is not a trivial change.  Why not re-load the data correctly instead?